# How to close connection with cassandra with node.js

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, cassandra

How to close connection with Cassandra in node.js? If I didn't close the connection, I will encounter an error.
The error is Error:

```
All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 10.XXXXX:OOO: Error: connect EMFILE
```

I have seen the solution in datastax. It suggest that it could be solved by the command: `process.exit()`. But it will kill the whole node.js process. That is not what I want. I just want to close the cassandra connection not the whole node.js process. Is there anyone has good solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

You should call [shutdown()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/api/class.Client/#shutdown) before exiting:

```
client.shutdown();
```

You can provide an optional callback.

You should only call `client.shutdown()` [once in your application’s lifetime](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/faq/).